# Teaching the Standing Wave Model vs Bohr's Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, atomic-physics, education, orbitals

In an introductory teaching level, what are the advantages and the disadvantages to teach the standing wave model of the hydrogen atom, (as in PSSC Physics textbook, 7th edition) versus the Bohr's model of this atom?

Comment: I don’t think questions about physics pedagogy are on-topic here. They seem mostly opinion-based to me, since I’m not aware of large-scale controlled studies of how best to teach physics.

Comment: For readers who don’t have access to that textbook, can you provide a link to explain what you mean by the standing wave model? Are you talking about little standing waves wrapping around on a circular orbit to explain why orbital angular momentum is quantized, like [here](https://www.lucamoroni.it/simulations/standing-waves-in-bohrs-atomic-model/)?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about standing waves wrapping around on a circular orbit to explain the quantization of energy, as a particle in a "box".

Comment: Let's forget about physics pedagogy. The question is: What are the advantages and disadvantages of the standing wave model versus the Bohr's model of the hydrogen atom?

Comment: @Ghoster Physics Education Research (PER) may touch pedagogical issues but is not physics pedagogy. There is a large core of analysis of physical concepts. If you are not aware of PER studies does not imply that they do not exist.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Please see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12700/questions-about-physics-teaching-pedagogy), which I think is the current policy: “questions that relate to how physics is being presented in teaching is off topic for this site”. Also “The biggest reason is because most questions like this will probably be opinion-based, which is a reason for question closure here.” This was precisely the point of my comment, which I now consider to be ratified by Physics Meta.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Note that in that Meta post, no members answered in favor of allowing such questions.

Comment: *The question is* You can’t change a question by just writing a comment; you can change it by editing it..

Comment: @Ghoster Current policy, or better opinions of community members, are not immutable. I respect other people's views, but I can express myself. I feel the ideas on meta you are referring to are not coming from a real knowledge of the topic. However, assuming that everybody understands this site policy, there is only one meaning of this question: *conceptual* advantage or disadvantage. It is perfectly IT, and answers can be based on facts.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Please consider writing a Meta answer in favor, arguing your case.

Comment: @Ghoster  I followed your suggestion I have expressed my opinion on https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12700/questions-about-physics-teaching-pedagogy

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thanks for posting that. I’ve commented there.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Schrodinger wave equation](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Chem_107B%3A_Physical_Chemistry_for_Life_Scientists/Chapters/4%3A_Quantum_Theory/4.10%3A_The_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Wave_Equation_for_the_Hydrogen_Atom) for the hydrogen atom and its solutions are waves, usually denoted as $Ψ$. The difference with usual wave equations is that it is not interpreted as a path for the electron in terms of (x,y,z,t) or (r,θ,φ,τ) but  $Ψ^*Ψ$ is the **probability** for the electron to be at that coordinate. That is why one talks of [orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) and not orbits in quantum mechanics. To compare the solutions  with data, one has to accumulate measurements, [see here.](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/58)

So the current mainstream physics is depended on solutions of the appropriate wave equations, and this is what should be taught. The Bohr model succeeded to fit a lot of the data, but it is phenomenological, dependent on arbitrary quantization and does not lead to the mainstream physics of today, except as part of its history.

Answer (score 1):

The standing wave model is simply wrong, if you must, teach them that and its history but be sure to let them know it's an outdated model, then proceed to Bohr's model, it's much more accurate, but once again be sure to tell them that even this is outdated but is necessary to know, then at the end, give them a small glimpse at the current model of an atom, with its clouds of probability!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that the clouds of probability stem from the three dimensional standing waves around the atom. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not that well versed in quantum physics so I do not know! You teach me.

Comment: "The standing wave model is simply wrong, " There was no standing wave  model before the Bohr model in the history of physics.